# How can I sync the draft folder in Outlook to our mobile devices?

Tags: outlook-anywhere

My company has a requirement to have the draft folder sync to our mobile devices. Exchange Active Sync doesn't support this. Outlook Anywhere does, however I'm having trouble finding a way to  support Outlook Anywhere--and in turn support draft syncing.

We use MS Exchange for our e-mail and iOS mobile devices.

Is there a way we can sync the draft folder in Outlook to these iOS mobile devices to comply with this policy?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Alexander, I edited your question to fit the site better since app requests are off-topic.

Comment: @TheCleaner, problem is, the only thing he can do is to use another app since natively it's not supported (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202803). So, this questions is and stays an app request.

Comment: Possibly so @Daniel but asking "How" and getting an answer that says "you can use X app" is actually on-topic.  Asking for an app is off-topic...offering an app as an answer isn't (unless you are pushing an app as spam advertising).  The answer could also be exactly as you stated...answer it as "Natively there is nothing that supports this.  You'll need a 3rd party app to do this, so you'll need to Google around and see what's out there."

Answer (score 1):

I place this answer here because I can't find a suitable question. But I see this question has been asked a lot on forums.

This answer probably doesn't address your question directly, but to synchronise outlook.com (web version, former hotmail) draft emails with iphone/ipad, I found a little trick.

Create a draft email on your desktop and save it in whatever folder you want. The first time this draft email will be synched with iphone. But when you adjust the draft email on your desktop, the new version is not updated in your iphone.

To solve this, after you adjusted the draft email, just drag it to another random folder in outlook.com (e.g. drag it to deleted items), and then drag it back to the original folder.

Now the draft email is synched in your ihpone.

It works the same the other way around, from iphone to desktop.

Comment: As you say, I am not sure that is the answer for this particular asker, but it is certainly an answer that could work (for individuals).